# Getting Data From Yahoo

Tags: stock, yahoo-finance

Could you please help me to fix code, which is taken partly from a book, below. It gives an error "The server returned the status 401 with message "Unauthorized" in response to the request to URL https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?period1=%EF%BF%BF&period2=%EF%BF%BF&interval=1devents=history&crumb=GAAvT/4ue2V."

Thanks a lot.

```
function [date, open, high, low, close, vol, adjclose]= downloadyahoo(symbol, period, start_date, end_date)
% download the data from finance.yahoo.com
% period can be '1d' for daily data, '1wk' for weekly data, '1mo' for monthly
% data
origDate = datenum('01-Jan-1970 00:00:00', 'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS');
if ischar(start_date)
    startDate = (datenum(start_date, 'ddmmyyyy') - origDate) * 24 * 60 * 60;
else
    startDate = (floor(start_date) - origDate) * 24 * 60 * 60;
end
if ischar(end_date)
    endDate = (datenum(end_date, 'ddmmyyyy') - origDate) * 24 * 60 * 60;
else
    endDate = (floor(end_date) - origDate) * 24 * 60 * 60;
end
% Create URL string and download csv file
url_string = ['https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/' upper(symbol) '?period1=' startDate '&period2=' end_date '&interval=' period '&events=history&crumb=GAAvT/4ue2V'];
urlwrite(url_string,['data_' upper(symbol) '.csv']);
import=importdata(['data_' upper(symbol) '.csv']);
delete(['data_' upper(symbol) '.csv']);
% Reverse to normal chronological order, so 1st entry is oldest data point
open     = flipud(import.data(:,1));
high     = flipud(import.data(:,2));
low      = flipud(import.data(:,3));
close    = flipud(import.data(:,4));
vol      = flipud(import.data(:,5));
adjclose = flipud(import.data(:,6));
for a=length(open):-1:1
   date(length(open)-a+1)=datenum((import.textdata{a+1}),'yyyy-mm-dd');
end
end
```

Comment: Are you definitely authorised to use this URL? Do you perhaps need to authenticate first in some way? The error message I get when I click on your link implies that there's a cookie missing, which would rather encourage the needs-authentication theory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer MandyShaw. My first problem is as you see in the message I receive the link has period1=%EF%BF%BF and it supposed to be period1= 1536212815 (which is second difference between input date and 1/1/1970)
So, the original link is: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?period1=1536212815&period2=1538804815&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=WnzSNf9PVJi 
I don't see a reason not to get data if I can fix my matlab code output. Am I right?

Comment: You are right, when I fix cookies it gives an error 

Error using error
Unable to find message key 'AuthenticationFailed' in catalog 'MATLAB:urlwrite'

Comment: There's nothing the community can do to help further until you have satisfied the authentication requirements of the service you're using.

Comment: It would appear that the service being connected to requires authentication.